# Are there any conditions where a MasterPage Page_PreInit() is executed?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Based on a configuration setting I'd like to direct users to a "This site is currently offline" page.  The master page seems like the common place to do that.  I originally used this code:

```
MyConfig config = new MyConfig();

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (config.RefuseRequests)
        Response.Redirect("Offline.aspx");
}
```

A break point here is never hit.

After some digging I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx which seems to say a master `Page_PreInit` is never called.  Am I reading that right?

The above code doesn't show an error in visual studio and it seems like a useful step in the load flow.  Are there any conditions where a master page `Page_PreInit` would be executed?

Comment: Untested, therefor only as comment: `MasterPages` don't have a `PreInit` event but `ContentPages`. So you could let all your pages inherit from a "Master-ContentPage" and use it's `PreInit` event. http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx

Comment: @Tim Given how quickly you said "`MasterPages` don't have a `PreInit`" the answer the main question appears to be "no."  Is this stated at MSDN or in a book (I obviously don't have) or somewhere?  Not having a reliable reference on this is what's nagging me.

Comment: [Here's a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx) of the MasterPage's events and [here's a nice list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx) of the sequence the events occur. I assume that it has no `PreInit` since it must be compiled and merged into the ContentPage. If it would have a `PreInit`, the ContentPage's PreInit [could change the assigned Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) what would cause unpredictable behaviour because the Master's `PreInit` would occur before the `Master` would be changed.

Comment: @Tim Those first two links go to the page I mentioned in the question.  I was hoping somebody had a more direct reference that said "they don't do that."  Your reasoning helps though.  Thanks.  With everything Visual Studio yells about it's disconcerting a master page `PreInit()` is just fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the information out there isn't as clearly stated as I'd like the practical answer does appear to be "no, a master `Page_PreInit()` will never be hit."